# im making a economy bot like owo but im getting operand errors

Tags: discord.py, operands

i cant figure out the error
it just says discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

what can i do here?

here is my code -

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import random

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="owo ", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as {} lets rock!".format(client.user))


@client.command(aliases=['c'])
async def cash(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author

    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]

    await ctx.send(f"<:cowoncy:1048582461610799116> **|** {ctx.author.name} you currently have **__{wallet_amt}__** **cowoncy**!")
    # await ctx.send(embed= em)

@client.command(aliases=['sm'])
async def give(ctx,member : discord.Member,amount = None):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    await open_account(member)
    if amount == None:
        await ctx.send(f" | {ctx.author.name}, Invalid arguments! :c", delete_after=5)
        return

    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)

    amount = int(amount)

    if amount > bal[0]:
        await ctx.send(f' **|** {ctx.author.name}, you silly hooman! You don\'t have enough cowoncy!')
        return

    await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount,'wallet')
    await update_bank(member,amount,'wallet')
    await ctx.send(f'<:CreditCard:1048583346453757992> **|** **{ctx.author.name}** sent **{amount}')

@client.command(aliases=['d'])
async def add(ctx,member : discord.Member, amount):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    await open_account(member)
    bal = await update_bank(member)

    await update_bank(member, amount,'wallet')
    await ctx.send(f'<:CreditCard:1048583346453757992> **|** {member} **{amount}** coins has been added to your balance!')

async def open_account(user):

    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

    with open('mainbank.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

    return True


async def get_bank_data():
    with open('mainbank.json','r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    return users


async def update_bank(user,change=0,mode = 'wallet'):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    users[str(user.id)][mode] += change

    with open('mainbank.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    bal = users[str(user.id)]['wallet'],users[str(user.id)]['bank']
    return bal

client.run("TOKEN")
```

i was making a economy bot and i got operand error what can i do here????
any type of help will be appreciated!

also you can dm me here † メ ☯ɪ ᴀᴍ ɢᴏᴋᴜ☯†ᴰᶜ#0001 if you want to ask something about the code...

Comment: What's the output of `users[str(user.id)][mode]` if you print it?

Comment: it edits the wallet/bank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly because of your `amount` argument in the command callback. Since it doesn't have a type annotation (or typehint), it will always be a string.

**Lines 62 and 63**

```py
users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0
```

The values you gave them are integers, but the `change` argument you passed into the `update_bank` in lines **41**, **42**, and **51** is a string; you can't add a string to an integer.

This can be fixed by adding `int` as the type annotation to the argument, so the library will convert the user input into an integer.

**Line 26**

```py
async def give(ctx,member: discord.Member, amount: int = None):
```

**Line 46**

```py
async def add(ctx, member: discord.Member, amount: int):
```